# Add IPtables rule by script at the request of another computer

Tags: linux, networking, script, iptables

I wonder, is it possible to make an script, which adds rule in iptables by request from other pc? I mean, script "knows" what to do, but addres for rule comes from request.

And how do you think it should be realized? 
I suppose, it should be deamon, or demonized script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to implement this using a server-side scripting language like PHP or Perl. However, since the input to the script is controllable by the user, you should be **very** careful in using it as input.

An example is below (I am not a web coder, so there could be huge security issues with this code, use with extreme caution):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

# Send HTTP content-type
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";

my $requester_ip;
# Do some sanity checking on the IP send by the webserver
if ( $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} =~ m/(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)/ ) {
  my $requester_ip = $1;
} else {
  print "An error occurred\n";
  exit;
}

# Open SMTP for the requester
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -d $requester_ip -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`
```

If you want to use this, make sure your webserver user can run `sudo` **only** with this specific command. *Again, this code is provided in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.*

It would be even better to do this in a two-stage process:

- Have the webserver write the IP to a file
- Let a seperate script run from crontab to get the IP from the file and run `iptables`.